# Generating LaTeX output from R data frame

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am running R v2.14.1 on Ubuntu. I am writing a script that will generate a data frame, which represents a table of results.

I would like to output this 'table' as a .tex file so that I can create an 'academic publication' quality table, for printing. I have heard of Sweave (and read some overview docs about Sweave) - so I think this is the way to proceeed. However having said that I have not actually seen an example where Sweave outputs a dataframe as a tex file - all of the Sweave examples I have seen so far, seem contrived and not something that I can build upon.

Are there some guidelines I can follow, to output tex from a dataframe? Also, will it be simpler (more straight forward), if I built the TeX string directly from my R script and saved the string to file? (It is not clear to me, what Sweave offers over and above manually building the TeX string 'manually').

Comment: also check out knitr. It is under active development and has more flexibility than Sweave.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [`xtable`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html) package has some examples of how to generate tables - see vignette. When you're writing a chunk, make sure you set the chunk to `<<results=tex>>`. See [Sweave example](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/Sweave/), for instance, [this](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/Sweave/foo.pdf).

This is how I would output a data.frame.

```
<<results=tex>>
    xtable(my.data.frame)
@
```

And the raw result would looks something like this:

```
> xtable(my.data.frame)
% latex table generated in R 2.14.1 by xtable 1.6-0 package
% Tue Feb 14 10:03:03 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rllr}
  \hline
 & p & q & r \\ 
  \hline
1 & condition\_a & grp\_1 &   3 \\ 
  2 & condition\_a & grp\_1 &   3 \\ 
  3 & condition\_a & grp\_1 &   4 \\ 
  4 & condition\_a & grp\_1 &   1 \\ 
  5 & condition\_b & grp\_1 &   4 \\ 
  6 & condition\_b & grp\_1 &   3 \\ 
  7 & condition\_b & grp\_1 &   5 \\ 
  8 & condition\_b & grp\_1 &   5 \\ 
  9 & condition\_a & grp\_2 &   4 \\ 
  10 & condition\_a & grp\_2 &   1 \\ 
  11 & condition\_a & grp\_2 &   1 \\ 
  12 & condition\_a & grp\_2 &   1 \\ 
  13 & condition\_b & grp\_2 &   5 \\ 
  14 & condition\_b & grp\_2 &   1 \\ 
  15 & condition\_b & grp\_2 &   5 \\ 
  16 & condition\_b & grp\_2 &   2 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think the '=' is missing in the Sweave code? `<<results=tex>>=`

Comment: I am trying to apply this proposal here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366637/16920

Answer (score 19):

I often use the [`latex`](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/StatReport/summary.pdf) and [`describe`](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/Hmisc/counties.pdf)
functions from the [`Hmisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package, which allow a lot of fine-tuning.

```
library(Hmisc)
d <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:5], x=rnorm(5))
latex(d, file="")            # If you want all the data
latex(describe(d), file="")  # If you just want a summary
```

Comment: +1 for interesting approach. I'll be sure to try that too at some stage.

Answer (score 18):

Use [`kable()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) from `knitr` package to turn a dataframe into a LaTeX table from R. [`kableExtra`](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) package allows doing more fine-tuning.

```
# Toy example 
df <- tibble(x = c(1:3), 
             y = c(4:6))

# Plain latex output 
kable(df, "latex")

# With Booktabs 
kable(df, "latex", booktabs = TRUE)

# Using kableExtra 
df %>%
    kbl(caption = "Example", # Adding caption  
        format = "latex") %>% # Output format = latex 
    kable_classic(html_font = "Cambria") # Font = Cambria
```

Comment: Criminally underrated answer. Probably a longer example using `kableExtra` features will engage future readers more.

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas Thanks for the helpful comment. I added one example of using kableExtra.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like manage all my code from within R rather than an Rnw file when I'm outputting summary tables and not writing a report, by using `cat()` and `sink()` this allows you to work from within the current environment rather than forcing everything to be loaded and reloaded everytime you need to rerun the document. Also, it makes it a bit easier to use R to "duplicate", "paste" or "loop" through large amounts of data or lists of data. Should be noted though, that this somewhat breaks the idea of reproducible research.

Here's an example of what I would put in an R file (remembering, of course that \ needs to be escaped \:

```
dat <- list()
for(i in 1:15) {
  dat[[i]] <- sample(c("A","B"),1000,replace=TRUE) # Dummy data
}

sink("temp.Rnw")

cat("
\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage{Sweave}
\\begin{document}
")

# Print a lot of tables
invisible(
  lapply(dat, 
       function(x) 
         print(xtable(table(x),caption=names(x)),table.placement="!htp"))
  ) 

cat("
\\end{document}
")

sink()
Sweave("temp.Rnw")
compilePdf("temp.Rnw")
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is with the R package xtable. You can very easily generate a LaTeX formatted file that

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
y <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
df <- data.frame("x"=x, "y"=y)
print.xtable(xtable(head(df)), file = "./Data.txt")
```

Then you could add the contents of "Data.txt" to your LaTeX file with

```
\input{./Data.txt}
```

A more quick and dirty solution that simply redirects the text output that's normally printed to the console is as follows:

```
sink("./Output.txt")
head(data)
sink()
```

You may also use cat() to add individual comments